# How to deploy an application with firewall permissions on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, firewall

I've bundled a jar file as a mac application using jar bundler. I'm now trying to create an installer for this app so that:
1) The application will be placed in the applications folder
2) The application is added to the list of permissible apps in Mac Application Level Firewall

Also, I have several example files I would like to include with this application - what is the best way to make these available to the user. Someone suggested I have the mpkg file launch a dmg file which would contain these files, but this seems circuitous.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apple's [PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), included with Xcode, can install the files along with your application; but that's usually done for files that need an absolute path. Alternatively, just distribute the application bundle and example files in a `.dmg`, and let the user allow or block the connection in `System Preferences`. As a convenience, you can include an alias to the `/Applications` folder.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182250/creating-a-mac-osx-installer-so-the-installed-app-wont-set-off-the-firewall). Signing the .app will prevent all but the first firewall warning. (Same as with major programs like Firefox). Signing the app is a hassle, but there's the benefit. I don't know of any Ant task that can help here.

As for packaging I suggest the JarBundler Ant Task [here](http://www.informagen.com/JarBundler/). I have added it to my build process and it has saved me lots of time. And last, an Ant Task for making the dmg [here](http://www.rkuntz.org/pmwiki.php?n=Code.AntDiskImage).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how/if you can change firewall rules, but few people run firewalls on Mac OS X anyway (no, really).

So I would just add instructions to your documentation about what ports to open if the user has enabled the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can't circumvent the firewall (for obvious reasons), but the user will be asked on first launch whether to allow incoming connections.