# How to Suppress the keychain prompt when the app modified?

Tags: macos, keychain

Hi Im using Mac 10.5.8 . In my app im using my own keychain(created by me), but my actual question is when I modify my code in the app every time a prompt is appearing, saying that the present app is modified do you want to allow or not.Can any one tell how to supress this prompt(allow by default when ever I change the app).I couldn't find the solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The Keychain has a list of trusted applications, and this list includes a hash digest for the application. When the application changes, it becomes untrusted again. This also happens with "big" applications like Camino.

There are two special measures to reduce this: When a shared library gets updated, the system will keep track of this and accept the application even after the update. Also, when Software Update updates an app, it will fix the digests as well (which is why Apple's own apps can get away without re-confirmation).

**Update**: If you sign your code, Keychain will also [accept updated applications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html) (signed with the same certificate).

Comment: Does code signing affect this? It certainly does for firewall approval dialogs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182250

Comment: @Rob Keniger. Indeed, it does! Code signing would solve this problem: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html